# conversion from float to int (weird behavior)

Tags: android, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I have this shader to implement character animation

```
uniform mat4 u_mVxP;
uniform mat4 u_mBlendMatrices[54];
uniform vec4 u_vDLDiffuseColor;
uniform vec4 u_vDLAmbientColor;
uniform vec3 u_vLightDir;
attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec3 a_BWeights;
attribute vec3 a_BIndices;
attribute vec3 a_Normal;
attribute vec2 a_TextureCoordinates;
varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates;
varying vec4 v_Color;
void main()                    
{
    vec4 vPos;
    vec3 vNormal;
    int i=int(a_BIndices.x);
    int j=int(a_BIndices.y);
    int k=int(a_BIndices.z);
    vPos=a_BWeights.x * a_Position * u_mBlendMatrices[i];
    vPos+=a_BWeights.y * a_Position * u_mBlendMatrices[j];
    vPos+=a_BWeights.z * a_Position * u_mBlendMatrices[k];
    vNormal=a_BWeights.x * vec3(vec4(a_Normal,0.0) * u_mBlendMatrices[i]);
    vNormal+=a_BWeights.y * vec3(vec4(a_Normal,0.0) * u_mBlendMatrices[j]);
    vNormal+=a_BWeights.z * vec3(vec4(a_Normal,0.0) * u_mBlendMatrices[k]);
    vNormal = normalize(vNormal);
    v_Color = u_vDLDiffuseColor * max(dot(-u_vLightDir,vNormal),0.0) + u_vDLAmbientColor;
    gl_Position = vPos * u_mVxP;
    v_TextureCoordinates = a_TextureCoordinates;
}
```

code runs perfect on galaxy s3 and s4 and my characters have thier animation correctly.
but in sony xperia Z and galaxy note3 they are rendered only in bind pos with no animation!
after a lot of test i found out that when float converts to int in xperia z and galaxy note3 it only return 0

```
int i=int(a_BIndices.x); // i is always 0
int j=int(a_BIndices.y); // j is always 0
int k=int(a_BIndices.z); // k is always 0
```

i even used this code

```
int i=1;
```

but i is still 0. could anyone help me what is going on

Comment: are the android Systems installed on These devices the same. Maybe older Versions or custom roms?

Comment: those devices have android 4.2 and 4.3 but my app should run on every system with android 2.2 and higher.

Comment: yes sure, but maybe a Kind of different android Version behaviour instead of a device behaviour? Try to make an Output of the original float value..are they different too?

Comment: Why not use (int) Math.floor() to remove the ambiguity?

Comment: i even used this code: int i=1; but it didn`t work so (int) Math.floor() will not work too!

Comment: By the way, your bone matrix array is ***larger*** than OpenGL ES 2.0 implementations are required to support. It takes **864** uniform components and ES 2.0 implementations only guarantee **512**. Likewise, you will run into trouble indexing uniforms with non-const expressions on some implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out that i should use vec4 array instead of matrix array!
its weird but solved my case